# Graph Get Subscriptions NextLink URL invalid

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I do a Get for /subscriptions (https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/subscriptions)
and then when I issue the nextLink URL I get a 404 HTML page.

Json for Get:

```json
{"@odata.context":"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#subscriptions","@odata.nextLink":"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/subscriptions?$skiptoken=NPt3S7g2KIxJBA0KWwQetW02oM%252FCUSHk7pYMytwSvL7oN1iL2ocP6a72PQ3HMq0buuiqx%252Bz0bb1izmOqtneSkq%252Bak92SoH181NzcqWADl2KetsedtInAsoohm7lUqSseqEyqnXy9c7Sph6eeEj8KkH2MqJaDqvR9%252BG%252F63RzFhLtGi9BRZTU36PV8dugvCSfKQwcaLd%252BRQ1lWzGctHWbXIstn1nyelZ1U8tatCZu8r5wXv8cllhEqvRuvjk%252F7Xk2hIPwS%252B6x1oKlaFxl%252FB7BVYfMVnVrvaWFKdvNuVTpFBmZ8XulWjVq%252BdAaE8a%252FilFG0XVoYcF3kub%252BjWkS53bywgCVqHm95ZidFbSJlTzFWjRpdFzf4uY06YJwibHHSt%252BW%252FPbugn4kDaj01p8AlMWOdsVwoVj7gFBazYvRl7lCIQZy19dcoMGLD%252B0A2pOrCUvKADna0rfpF2CnaJMBQwa7Z8eBzmR1bFxphK9AtIrpSDu05af6cNp2bRWqySeAAHi5BIoso1CCCKoWV2nAeeANizo1xZSIPf6KnZw%252BjH%252FDZo%252FtemrattI3mzmSUboPC5SNzQwNTdpDsMCMXivCKG8tYHfeu%252FEDzM%252Bmy2eXlAUvQKAsfZ41hJ30kO5Sbs2ShKw%252FbzZa%252FzhFstV%252B9Pl%252BmTTUc2VaVfQPg4QbhXzP%252BQxWtyl2DlY7R9eDzgSoW6lsdmS%252FltwLqXPEz%252BpIL%252BKeM16jDcv%252F7DYweO%252Fl%252BoYT5guDO4HVTucHrDzaPru1QEqUO10bcb%252BQ04XsUCHTJnKViXooqboctOhj2Yz96u7N%252BcBnyRCLbwnk%252BBXgFCHlhEpDUqFj1z0FtltujoOICKvbVzfdfeWhu3GHl6YqK1ErHEUBj1JT7vxsJN%252FqOnWFp3b4JwXS9q3kUGTFU2DeYGKW7DTDxJsN%252Brx756p8lwo8r8BnnquSGN0y1rDxjVEzFZJ%252Fv%252FaO80hThSetR50iY%252FeT8gOFqvRagIgqcuSKDNAiADmRXBAcPuY9Xlb56KzwKgelNI%252FhEoynaq9m9qywQtkvF1Mx7vQmnJPzkbwIEmJXIZKIbQR7hRsnhpiQY0zLZwh%252FEPPDQyZ3rvnaNruAyFx6QuqKuDefVNUvExjqUg5KQLyP5XnlWAfsaSuFWJY3wrp4WnkoxOKFnG2mJRyQBw3WjGhOBA68lbQXJmlzxVQA9zbXXlbha%252BbRo%252Bs3UIYvDmGUCfYxv9u0jiIenDGEaKBnia7QshVDClSwTn1cZjtOeNt2lORu8bwasrc5gA1gh6LftSa1cJoMApolb1rm4iko7u3u5y6m1FWa6l06dF4XWdOYJfY23LdaWwZXKfAVpp1bJAJ1zjUzPA5vzXkIxUj44A0OCwdgwe03aIzUAUeWpiCOBCWmeu8hEKfBYNZii75aB3Km25a5jmjR6JSXc7yqoEa91FVUDkbDpf7zqTaiIEAYZu7jjTeSmE9Ut11Qi4V17TzNPruX16zb%252FfTysfacnENXa8Cr48jMPKqU%252BVk3Waut4rr7IjrsOwPDgODKFD%252FIYtm4P5GU1SLLv3cLv4K93OFv6qWcdp7%252FhPpDJHhbqG9xvsR8bKIkUP78BbOcuke4zklTI0BBkvQce9mEDaUL%252FPquTD5%252FUnkNsgMhNycatCEHt%252BzBvL3B23JU1Awp7d5UO2ZdO%252BOmlBK91z6RxZIy7a9rbSyVBltzj3AZPUzq2sLhqbGDZaxkTkqao%252FtnmJoqKC9BD0U%252BW9QFXVoqNPUg3WQyseZI4CubyPKjflo6rf%252FRp4AcS%252FzpcL3bKjPewzmzJJOF%252BGCKbBtXuYvYUmpp3cK25gv6YKg2I3SRWC7B4pj3NyEpPil4pXdb7DpYlk0yxd3LteHQ0%252FkSSVNLW%252B%252FUq5R5QouKEt1tZXPnBDT3GoWQyt7UDkGpF1oG%252BtjQNieecEAcdEb02u4E83g8h6oprXnqNGIh32rxyuYmYt13sbADhYeXgLs6nb6olC8ciHast7rTNZl5gL7aB%252F3b%252FTeAhiiggPY7WS%252F3s%252Bl4hWZHtQI85CidcxmEZUX5h1UvZ863z%252B65cAYec1wKVxRKIES%252F5gWetPMKJizfxlhjV66jhHCcPBoEczKYMm5U7XvWHxOxGCGQX%252FB10MfsBF77xxH4Hb8E8rtGhsp5rX4ihC3P5C83WB6d5ZmhggQnFhdwSt1T4v3Nz4oUhHA21E5ddeesyBN9%252BQIpsis%252FCJTIhHU0Mnnx3Xk9tj5HX0BCi9QzMq%252FEOTEWu00bXUv0zz2%252BZEHjUaVY8JMc9tr4lc1vQa%252FsKi048H7wNHRr4MAq%252BDCzYJn9qQspPVuKND2CfPrJLQa5qKKjgJmKmwaTH09Tk6V%252BDNOjzEJ0LOmi2FCQCMIQZnLxaqNeuF9isvAX%252BvHuWS1hLfw8fsITViebIjdPJthWPfmzWG3%252FkFG6XQ4U%252BXjeJkhsi%252BEzTmKMbG83cHkxwU6%252F9LUJHAKiHOjv5nVs%252BczVQiu2qhYQsgSaMli5WQAVyLWP%252BhOWbxKQoDPsnsSjEstEJmjsQlM5mWPYA%252FPfHi8W%252B2mSkD1Q3TDaqbc6oXWWPigrjbl2aVmp4V2yBqWgfovS7cV9EncamdIT0YENVsM2LDx8K2Zh7twchFpYwB9Tq3iMNMDoXGsykGt0adWH3RCmnbUW44xWdr2mdXd6RjoDZiJP9odg9ha2ysH759tR8Tcfm4qv3dENaKANY3RJXsDEx%252BG%252B9sNwJNOI0N6GWWY96F%252BT8ZIMU5K%252FRyc3H91DQnnI2TsKmZs2ujN7FIQzc1OkIT4UAmcIKqJq%252BGlT%252Bp9vmt%252BdZHTecJ9URabv8LYx7IO32oKmexSRszpG7EI0QtsrZl1aTp7FIefHDNgr24dBoy2kN%252Bvx7YcX%252BjN%252B525MKM7%252F1pae%252Bx2V9WG1pyzrs7NwriEEvHp0n1DE%252BBRi3iJh5WtKUyMNysknvRlfTM5NxauopIT5kIpFntV1KPBsAKljC0p6S7jJIxX4liTvBK4dnoddK%252BlTNc9%252BQcS4dpo21v9R9jnaSCLP3Hwjy7AdAWo%252BDXd7doSfM6MQmeB2RnO%252F5H2XNGGL%252BtWo3TJPMEHapbkmQzJceB2bAq8r%252F4cZNNk8kteDjuAvbaQWuYtxZ8ocTqwCP1KT21%252B5NZtKv5qtCXhBKfGm8GaGa5mP0Sg8v8fcQxrs70XyHFzliAqovjMUKsN95tZ3oD8LoFfMsUHBNG5r6Qo65Pob0VtbTXTQQw5JQBHVKoeUIEkxCwJLRdMA%252FBO%252B8tS%252FEBwKhsa71TLFttHxF9jNHCFJ4mH2G%252B%252FCnwlGkq2idDkYn4GuU0riYJbcboedAR3OA%252FyoHC9JFkUB2aD4JVrKt8bppKrrGmq9eJfnsJhdV5yzWH6ig04In1IfC4tizKbQurRYNu0V55gJg9b6D3vsK%252FIeDTOM29SNhmmgbfrLeE%252F8EsgVtiQDHq8FCokeNYsbKaiXU2GMGmQ0C7ZxBKTBhnKKeVCk%252BNSB8jLgwg3PvrSf29Kv63dOHtyZbn6BBYkDwsgWXx1QdOH3xOUUTHdaxHxTXzGrdBwnU5zj%252Fmzgp30pVVpYyjFt6t5c8zHxBeFSHbSH%252BqCWLkFohHeH66oLd1mFqKqFg%252FMpdgZNY%252BKn41fUPh0qjFp%252BJp7XXrxx6qwq3YARd5ITUAcTKtKSNCtIbw3L9N%252FeLWXYbjIK3GI6fm2hHuDOwKG0K8bfQLdej7LYtfz1vdYZEh1cGO%252FvpcRXPwQ0GSf3%252BNfQeNymqVWKykc4WFteZiptWeO43c1cDTYJU4pEmW1O5XFOh4Zh4OzsTNQAdejrpW3sBFyHLeCm%252BDIOmcKQ9LNTJgtsCAaOanNIf2M5Gqu0iMqsRZMpmE5y7Go1%252Fyt9I%252FL8wezxxU0GCCmrwcVtyQ%252FF7ls8pBZwp67Q95cYTgL9XCCxrjmnUeoAQScnOqKsbtty0r3gGMIRyX5hehZ41j%252F2TocfSiI5n7Ic%252FdGUfldD9bRLQCq7RK%252FrbqGJwIO8iicObvJ0lWCgMR69eL63fmz0q96%252BUH4x6CNe00lXuG83uXTAUSbK9Epw2V%252BfSWYXjwLqW4Q6O5XaUsud4%252BgXzPv%252BM5YGIhGYe%252BfVSxLu0a36VkC5L974X9rDd1J7aH5kdreahPeYA%252FM5L%252FJ2ab0KA4yYAKfIhhxWy5m7lBY%252BmxY63jU%252FwxfFJwpO2KxmE1PzyiH5Rf6%252B6PTvWRMCNyMzpOOIyIxVifqdejc6IyP0ZG%252FmTPDmvTc8NDcZtRPoRZuNBly%252BqxPAC45xsihql30ohMqJecsnM46kWeHOuFpawOZ%252BFgq%252BbZBeJN%252BdV5Rh6YuICFupn3BgvowuowDfVWEqM9%252BY3%252BNwHZ2rLPDc6taytaeIJHE0hri2%252FJTG3kY2yNz9KPmaNqxddunAFeOUXyntiE3gVNa9Zl0jRbcV6CGe8Vfqf6Gad7Ke2IrEjVTmuIr2D6wYen5iRWxOhLqSy0IMhNxGkI%252FRNnAGAfoE%252BYwe8ae7XKYsBn8IWqpcdY3A6JJt1u3DO4Bujklx1nbDrdUrUbfVXVGXNrJuj%252Be9tBcn%252BmRFQPp0n%252BSYiKhGkKSYCfalyqXgogK3v7M3ce62TaNLo0au1QohlcftIEs%252BDAjYYVEzgzp0frU1SS%252BrMy3tCi5HR%252FUrwOz7S3xAdILMywEkk36bXNgGamEWMCvOkcN9Yu4w9OK4JglwqzF0Y7Weq11jCzpoAm1CqITZx%252F%252FYaVqtvYReIkstTagezFAJJ%252Byymvwetr3gQ7ZEsfy3N08UugXXMTkjVbxsjVzzH6p9lME54yY51QHa5e%252BWZ7Nox%252BfvqM9k0UlYDd1S2OO8ean5%252Fh5Z3U%252FxYoxAEcYaMnkjrZXaraIoVz9YvZCVgW72ru2nQ%252B2O90J7V8%252BsvBFtI9cVqxkll%252FkwyoXOuCW53XZwF%252F4kWRzfpaOU%252FXPBjx6tfT4crc%252FrckVODf3P3IVjpjJwsHz0pphIF%252FGyW4WgYb2VrDW63906NUx7UyEdLkedxSP38h%252BZXT8Yre53dwIbxde5tDSXTeBEpi%252Byb11s8n%252F8zin5mTkf5PeqMEHhARM4wJVRJMmgRjPfeeK8NfeU8QUTxPZWF9tD7rRJxYDK2kK9WFwSFRZv7YHLOh9ZA6M4M5KD1VkJfjVawRp7jQi02%252F1YT1pWRKp3%252BpQ6grn2XIWBCMnJ48n1Vpeag5bDlcvqUBm%252Fuckjc5qn9bwypLcCLcYUqDBJV1uxaWxFwedUT4KKeNYoxt%252FyxMXINQioofWcdOTDEJQ2%252B%252B3gbn5Ua6V75PnjaFGsEkAJ721ARrs6AaLZYQidJvD6nZrv94qe4urs2U%252BCwqscrbaFmkAO%252B2dF%252BWGNDxzljwhPt8wgqrwEN31FoP5eu0eEbIL6k5NoBet5bFSxhU220PPxRJJ9YCPHnzgzB27BZXfW%252Bp28JN%252FYCsm7Od8yiIQHNNy6fu09132AFc6jcfGAooAcMkgpxOuvxlOfOalBdpbHdFveoSj79JhtFLlSS59tKpuCBq30DavL2whqB%252BifHRGzwR%252FCfCtrlFlsLsULLHBnsbbnHfuDt3WMWTrqoft2RiDmFEleDx1U1nHbZx13ENGOe8UGX2BmjGREftU0k7hU760Ti730yPliTPPgBlEr4GNidGaAXw5sm7kW5yEvMeHdei5ouK7yczExgBvXg7LW933rDf7Q0qoagrCQhOkliH0%252BkVEGnR59Zczdcve0yOiYIiZ66ngSkuMdFo6owomK7PL%252FxB7Ss272fxW77VXzGnkABOpOoeDhhPxKLRGYH1vDgBb053NvEsxbaT8Ulvxj6hfURYYBYvA2TECFupLREcc%252F7ZV8IyfEp8SEL4ug610al53%252FRSVK46%252FoLseZ0yfoLSKXw3aBNYwfnmlgYytRsrQUr3fyIMV7Ep%252BAA5L08ySylkiI9i0k2ylbzqWdton6OjO0jjXd9bWrvjjTOr9pnPsOxCtyT8OsUcuick2CaEA6LM1I6IIG08C82Nja6zHWpgzySCl3JFFiYRyaGPNMydufEGHQa3ZUlJMMygcJqKyrpee1f6JBr5CGsKPRpAEOBy1wazYyv759yzu4hM6HFLkOrzRayMPLFN%252FahyR0FNCtsB%252BScCKOel%252BHqLD2dyfDyap5JT6wjuSOMoucQ5LTdxJaoiIkJpIFe9RoEMgSp2%252FrrnwIS17THJT3uDTqcKNnGkJy1m1DOlWQePTp3sbkikRUmYB3LCjqV8WrvOdugWEnOE%252F2Ht%252BYIcs9ivHljuKriertwzQbgBH2d0ZTvTghQtNsDrA1sMDCvET68%252FHdRW7oDNPZsAout%252F2Xdg04zPrf8HbKDKBJvAshVsoMEzGcHzollt9wepofGMuhAdYUe6VDYMan09vHV8%252FWIXoBcP4Zs5dJsUUJoMkZ7Vo4FlKNOlM0xXu6lBRwBfHxhzZvjq%252BJ572ViLC7ClBsKWIAkOqm0mKL8oy%252F90H64jRIsmcVDqdArCB2loCBz1dg1p4LP0k6ztacCcO14qZ7StLjWcPg%252F6h2m6MWru%252Fhq9N8wkDMf0EiavaqkgBjli0wUW2tO3ont6OpQ8QbgpLy4V%252F%252Bq7cTkUWcLW6CKvbaIT2AmNH95ao0b0W10sO3uMBH1zdVbBIcL7XE6xUtXCJn4BUtdISBdYoX4mgKnGehmE5lsCJFuZg9f%252BJIC2Aci3IOHGrwxt6HFCrLmBZnTk7D6u%252B2T3Yw9fZlyuFHUd%252F6mmoxHJkBDaj7p%252ByvkHE7Y01vaC3OcUDBi3E%252FgxWrTI0IYRm9YKKbY7b4EtQkRoR0QxsGMC0W6f2ASh332e9Jbm9fApn1p1NeLLs%252BwQFr%252FNfY3F7yb4As4bzTWqPvRka5BWEf%252FQycPfXtUSSbEZ36z6hzhH6tJOi9LkFrrpkRMjivzJODGLyY5BXF3LmtpmNqF1UstaKdHfssMd5NEXbhgg%252FchIFfQ6D4S8pm4V03zQjYhM6oIqCRN1l30BkROIMx5Fe0Ul8VxbEZP1Du%252FrwnF2gcbA18hlTWOOeYcNX8zPTPsOPUAhxtkFuDV%252B8LHcyKtQbQdflfoUDJKRUfsll4bBoSAmOSSqp3AYR5mtsvnJ1gzoY24szm%252FU1Thuv2u0pImvvEeMzKzS%252FrvmpLrVWxEkJckWwmHt0Ey1aOtl4Zkb9S4rLRF1%252FJfrCxXet7MhFIE2GP6zO%252BYqboFh6PDQKv3cC8ZAMezooZYtl0sZQuWGiqQxH5SYZUis7VmfUOo81JawjA1ZjFqk%252F%252Fa93%252FmGJRzKiQY4iZAHN6PvFLHBy7lVgcmLt%252FpBk9Dn28efFkQnkINIZWswuzHO%252Fw3IDTBhuHmV6IVzCgglIKz1SwuLF7y0gQoryDZU8FQ53p4PmLoXGxZA6qNOw7w7R%252B680cgngtvinm1WEAe1elErwDY%252FMwwgUrg5HnvMxsyWBXQAM3o3RCmBj%252BnuVI4cIufkQTfL7MWPTslHf41lN1Y%252FNxeOmNcPRvzGyjOTs5W2Rkhdv24PDtNL2yHts9FZHEiU4p4mhPA6hUNhGVJLAUDkgh0SQBFmwNNS7Z9YcCYkdvylAKwZAATVypduoWx%252FOJZa0BQA3tDu8OlRcaZaOarW5dJSXazmlcpDxr9ze48%252FJ4yru%252FZfkBb6T%252Fk7RkvpefzCRJl3nG4Z60ak2dy4yr5WRw%252Fd39GoVWEZh9iVzRP8sJAGJIfYfVvMwPndJElFV%252BQeDv1mDVYv1jaexqVlxDX0aC9EZ8o0HXqHf3dLKhL1mAtQeFcRcEbYFoyzvCf6BkbinVik60PSFyBr7Fw2b07FXgTMD9fBW6OYWQqfYGCIkQrSuqXiASry%252Fvj0aFLitNLbJO7gNS5yZLLHuiILMjHh6X0ES%252BEGVSteIOU0U%252F4C9lC39j%252FXKsHwlMVwfaiFN5%252FUfM4Qt2gL%252F%252F%252B1lqL%252BitoAsqa82h35RRgF%252BaXAQ99zDg9w4UW%252FhBQ1Uqu6XzWKUMbpb8qr%252Fd5jHEDpEzNVudz4Bh8LRMLYOmokAJEqKsm34ieDVyYermFATYQM%252FQdZfeGwfuHl5rr1J60Gv8%252BGiwZDtAavrF0lSzGqPaAyPsvc4VjCS8Y8vDB43EYGLEm5IEnXYLTREerU9e5LzTD774sq8ikIDoz0M%252Bts2nsn%252BRYshqCG20wluHgvJSLZHtb4k4Xq85qhPcNQWVEq98qRoW0F49nxaC2OiN%252FXiLEtce0nKS9dFQ1T%252B9ksBtadw2da4BV43fFP2aLR1yE0TdKQ0qmepozi%252B33T%252BhRsLWV7RQ8CKVO7iOEtz2y69DGsueOZC8v1E9PfwvQKprwO95iBEQpP7OitkaP%252FrPgq8bGgWi48ggEV5tGXJlNOboK8vNukIha0l3DgS5Gv4dD%252F6M2rXluU1lHdD4w5W1QgQLJHZRJvM%252BktfhJ%252BT%252FYXn2XeZobM%252BfjOv6CzP9Bwjo%252FPzgMDzUkL2JcACQid%252FOpqeMH5RwFbSSFW8raiu2NhnlZKqneGgzyf4RgkUZi6CpGNz%252BE3BrOaPYpkWCLV8ZYX7oav%252FmwtiZZA4XfQLXvhJ8aP5xLm95K%252Fxc6DGY0gQN8sblhQEpkuC40wPAUqo%252BpON6EYjBk4tNhUwbUAVnFpASkjLQu8VWxOZ1dQaMHQBRqSlt30L%252FPE3E%252Fwnz2S5dZaAjAxeHGdwzivk2uNmA8kiBoCD%252F6Mthe6v4YO66ohyc%252BWRZP%252FXhjMuKfbN6LhMGFSKz2tAUEGrrLug63eWF%252FEDEZCY5TBzLFbca9iR50fhHRwzbfRkMLE8vikUMxFYjhM716%252FBKG793svVgYTMbnyWfz2OdDmFQ7arsOmEjnS9bERpPAA9nlFlNvo%252By%252FHXN45ErfuVBt1UrmZnkFe07%252Ff9EM48QyQ7v%252F3I5miCvFNHNoOVuSKtJ5WOMIGAucuaD4tdPP%252FUIvX4wc6b%252BhBiSXLZ7KtOSBpievewD1OUJDKrKTAM6axXi8RwaT7VvXN60mfMqUR%252BtJxaQ%252B40S9%252BD1vphVKC7UysHmvSk5Al9dX3s4Z4FvrnTvmY10d7Rc4A3wd9F%252BTKqDzcND6LCGNzS5f326I%252Fuwekcj8sx3RsXDXJ7Zf%252BCGpeIvxd7OC%252BgXhKBC7QWTcIM9CrTwDmmB6JgBXvz4xtiE0uJj2%252B2TGAZ7JV0mjtuAhZE14Kvd5hryGbfkBl1%252BfzxPGwmKnDKa0W8dxb%252FQRiLD9k3f8BKlcV2NZUGj83PlLTbYzlvlzCPW9jCflHf0CSZO9gL5xLxB7WtmLog1E5inKfAWntLoYpDBA4edWtB5qWTqh%252FeTJzJjepqSrYWRw8fVEutfjxV6xdKFEll0ACbm5An%252F62b89fHcAx30QJSW1Uzv1uuxrv6g0ZMj2r4Pvf2dwGefYmX5bd1xfIosz3ZaLYpFoOBjnrs8u5jccpdIBjg4lEOELwxJNX1zNXsfNyn6Uzk85Vb6U45gRWl%252BdsYPJsgWK15eb5UJbprdrEjoos2xKPqdvxns9Ia7fj2fjUfG%252F7Xa3%252FmBin2xVYbxRl%252BzyGxGZ%252B8sULbZKGjn%252BFwtVtj9Er9ZeMbJqxPrRWTE9Zsb7DfHx7ppUW6X1aTSFCKC1%252FPYkdsoKm1pCEg2OuOXMbMJUXhYAaR%252F6sEhzFeoC1DiZCFmbWpYA236iefYcPiSuYuTQpVsKz0vChxzUk2EEkVm%252FmNxqXtPj4IZDV7EvFQ2LC58rXkz2mJ7iIc2R37CUmh94Y6FIai76LxwIQu6gOPGAAzFeyDj1HgATvcpQPV5a1%252F%252FwgyGidqtc%252Bu%252FDaKxGgeBbsuhcf9kX6NOWExG2PmwH7PO0%252B9gkXs4mNP1uAUbrto5FTj9wmzn9eYeurIymVvVyO7IFucq1W9d%252FJ2TUvLP9ujfZpoDkKPML4EUrkHmqoY9ugjp4fFpnyNNMFfWwPG8kPp9I3EUTzbCp3v1SkFq8xE2QuFkweW1dcBJE%252F%252F2UKHC4WFIFV77vb09SYYGGV2KxO7LbmbT5rHCAZTU4F2C%252F08BgCI7bQnv%252FzhK2yOASFLprlE1NlE7SfksmpjOdp1VliPqp5TIv16OxsOsLAK2ZA%252Bkd01ACTOPfHfMrq%252FZR0E9iai5WeC2HbVQ%252FIAjwHkoSqQ5oeIMa45o6ZbWXzmHtSWE6%252BXlMiamyIV%252BUVjnurOSkpwRHEL2cf2BPGeDunHrTLkLf%252BxpU06xwdHFAyX6%252Bn3FFLCdk4Dp7OTVpxSulIwq9zenuA1O5OG9vqpTP47tjJglZcpOe7V9E6CJMP884u5pl9fLXLJ8q2PMId5DF45bMfdwAo%252BoQuevM5h5zE5mMJic76oo6cmm16tevob3IVFI8GTLG6HilRpRIn0yY7RvUzJf1G5uGmppVUvnEywiFlXC37Yy4%252BFTBrC2k%252FHRMcjIiuM4q5%252FugoNLwjIlWmUtpPiStfhwQA016A89ZoekzwPUmuIag71IOZ5q3rUCCB7Pk6%252BKC%252FMH1uSkx98loNngmxb9Q3gVW29XAt3eLkzrtp9aBwYsL69fCQLij7D7rxQP5EbIx5s1AZE%252FdoJuO7azdQGz8VyJR%252B66mjeEpinU8jdg7vsjPEbH8iA7TbZDdFNWWOvnCpDC0mRRNH96akHwWJl1zgfRDgCyD499AdH4HHqgasiiRrNxqKVaV8Uw54QPPYfkBKPXmklYFKZPWtlZjqrC8xb00hTxxfGGAHTWwUxbUgcAiTUzPShBZrfqy0IDm9xPX4P1ePnVMXIWiyV7J04juz8sejVXDwy%252FqgxGWXN2PIA5TJNFH4T%252B2eUiY3qoKgtOqhrZYsqYIqFyaskceZrpghB6wkwBCUVuGkxDCTz63NtcIUVVjiZEnChsk3LPap7BAUdtUS%252F8tcOITGWq4%252F4O09JCFFR7kz8BpasXfSCJceLyXHQ3qCK4lA6oAVqA1rVcPQihMN1gKSxTIUnfbhNshK%252FvWqcasFvR%252FtnT84IOELRbfkWggYGlOM4ALxizGAnC%252F6s%252FuH6LueoS0WPNLHbp9690o7tDFIuPOveKgSFi1qwX1rwb%252FQ6vx3JMMPxSV5I0AqIq50e2PbWa1FMD5ahElPNDTfSIw3N1GgW3Ma%252BA5izTkRvY1zDA%252Fvv6gTXWd85LrGca913X9UTek0k4zalZrJs2Nk1Fem8%252FFWH5AxG5hTP3AQTlrXG0J7mFXkaKapZl4bT1kh%252FMN539r73CrvP2glkrUtSmnytDckPaBqpZvmdvnYCCp0aPjgMtQ53K1ADfPTr6nTmqy0PAjZMINW2NNRAwI%252FKo9QO27wiEiW0UrRJmnnqZ1n26nj4IztxE6lIDsXD2uE5rLRHVqRw6wjo%252BpuxbFfxW1tmAQ6wdsu8E39ZUTyG9l2H1Hjndr4WPOVnRRjfsvLQhMYth2hlF8vOHJ0ORogfE4%252B7N413mABJtSCDysl0CyFAIzecpzOfNv8I92sgdL%252FXAyzxu98tfXVNS1%252FGs0Fce9SebafV0nWe1KhGwSqRgfA0QmvQQl%252FVfhe%252Bqovte5PPRQrx0BAIzdL15vHyktqjTT%252BpL1pLtaYgApOqHDiaYuc%252BjhcT6WiUXem8hUTWFrB%252FcI%252FBTBR4rpbB1Wg5L4eLmbLpldWW93Cs64CnlA9ov7BX7PvYyTnfG7UXZM755B%252FxEY6dXc1WY%252FC2aHPd4kqalpwt15PoRJorf9tzErX8jD3RZBS4DCbUYxLF0Z4intl5olPzBNNYgdz0G7E%252BBxGTnm4nx0e8ciKc485wLk1sk2pOY507AIjPhvwbpiP3foruNZlBPB4IQn9GPvzdjQGQN4zaC%252FQUKk1sB81LkS7CQOMPQJ8uRdDxqDO3URNoHe1yAs%252BR2V99MS2RgonllBjLtLgMJxLmwqMzuNA4X6GPEygQ9XFub%252BLrJRK70JDf4IWXY%252Br%252FIT%252FLDJvxOoivhe3BQI5fHBytKZQKhjdgNtbYpCbGlbN%252B1xW6i9F9NNKmu16RrdHa3kCk07ae%252FP9uzVuyPY0q7v7k2RpWtr16QPGwudYEmma60FIdObAw4j4%252FDT4L0sWOazqw2TLR518drprKO6z92hyluhI22MraJjU8KdjBIHB7D7yTzMgVIANmYcrMAQWquyif6UajxvjemjFiufmma5o6trnUbsx8SHUx%252Bowh40qx%252Bnj5N%252FQky5vuvOcWh1nGKLCj8YFfwI4e9dEq%252FVRxihGgJBxHyAtoZOIUP3Er1EqrNZ96qIrnNMtAiuzxqlY4HfYQH1YeCTCwvGniX%252FfQOiEDixfEepyEP64T1S0yZv8hfIjOTsoFbcHULa4kO5yXPMJ%252FLQwTjVrdcjVaIfRh2zhMLfaZ2dj6B30M731YYw4y6Qvo1raLlLnBlm1HKXt1zPU%252B8YHbUpshGyx6qDE34S%252B6SmkiLJUEJtVSv%252FGNyXdUWFtkcO6zz%252B8ZI3vH%252Ffl8n71dlXoYHd57cyhVSMlFz2bHY%252FkvAEA731xaCXe1JSqZBM%252FxDiRTRxkEd27xOmsh%252BMSt1sokKD4HzuuFc33%252BFqHyu0SH%252BrTW7Rp20uzuT0aLs09lkBbPOzjVOvXoXbwv48gDJZ%252BauOFGaYW6vjL%252F5SxAsoGOBiFSdbpSkzsfmCh6Fsi5buf2Go1bq%252ByMIwB1wi%252FVazyOrA0oOxIy%252FwNjRRFv%252FVdo696FGoQMkdwf3uK963Pqm%252Fs%252BnJoOYdmaoPMhaDbBArKB0TgyX0YlVIL3DHHu8dkx4bCz%252FtHGurT3OQBvK8t4Nj1w7Atb7TmKj6bHa0u3akk9ykQVfhSTOqKUZ9NdbT8YsvyW5r%252F3OfUxwQNFkB%252FvriThkG%252BXGL09TaTh4azGs%252B0E5VBaImsLix9S0qeFJrBByjwJ%252BrzFVnE8l6a0qcVMQcyZOYdih%252Fhb1EpSE0fHrspqfjsHItUI3lAmAJsY%252FlqYcGMLBVeWd6jHq4jR7JQrJCwjSpM4P8JNGY%252FO27tF5r7y4phKFpuGjsOQaNMPBKlPlH5XoWq8tYRYLEyjG0zYc20lwR7u8cnWMLLOfjVBB63EFnesblEsgdSqZKiVwZD5XaTPYrD%252BqdJJ%252F4l28sBt0iZ5GjEowhHjjSOAtiR1%252BR%252BAwGFOSfcdJcGlfujzMKtKcl%252Fa1rX34fGdlzodPwnk0%252BwlDXQcuuMuR%252FnHTNtosIH9Qb3s3PxeTGAsI0%252FmyspPoTJ4Lm0cQIuo0K0Bvw05vMkjKcvY2%252BS6Gwwl5EIERd%252FKDlJty22kSetrzOxZgBTtvFHpjmew%252B0Y9wAROaCOvNvzvJWD%252FmuJcmiacH7XEQOyzLMG6UBJEvCvSYFubJB8UfqBxqArflQX8c96tuzLtDSvQ%252FNXkZAEq%252BVmovn3Y6pz7S2RHz9DtYllvsWqn%252B6imqWifmWCCdE%252FQkOYyVNAEgwa4LC5%252BpP%252FkJ9qFouLtYgsvAaP5R0fkHD%252FReACcyRRCb4M8%252FM9IBRsjJY%252F3cfg%252FxpgVNYy%252F2hxohdzxzMWTjT0zdhHCuCeE9OhIucPbBpkL0mvX1qX05mxT3PIDLQFYy3V%252BHzdBSm6BtdDsRhYy6KlHNdOCgIdw8dz%252BvinqguaD8LOFV5L45I4gp8gmzvAv9a1TMSN1rcDJo7gkcwha9UNkLGby4jQx7qcw5dYGUHMsw0x38CBG8adNBKLO54biryYJMEsYHhvJ8Bh7gDJMDzPqGd%252Bcww52jdk7Tv0J8JYH9BTAPsNQbP9beRi0tGDcV8yuxKGn16UQZuh0dtD5boxnreZrVOn8VmGPI1amV0MJvemwQ7z3Nyv8SOuCaCDVjBYdIn66jQ7q6yuR%252FyeURoelLj3ssS7FFGKUKgue3N7gQgjKRLHlLYIEWo2zTm%252FEWpdrvWCMXHsduHHky4q71LWAmciilw%252B2uM7cHCz2BNZLv2B0K4MJRE8YlRDnmxjTuusqp5FO0oA4EhMLGVgAnaF0qDJ%252B4Rjj8tSk8hCmCiwuGvZJHidAqyw5TWUrLEPFzIVbtKRp%252FMNsnB6PnGgxaRkZ4wS6MSnnWSJipIBihlliRJbMpNMEJY0BPBfODPGGO3wrKVK%252BbhW5B3uACnOV9r%252FVP17U3BpzDNcI2PePFcEhAyksWPNS3kN%252F57L%252BpItlc3SyT%252BzsIs1cyieE%252BMeOyg5Nim6ZKte5beql58zMk14CcBJMlVaQVZYM66S4Ui8lPz3zQ8psdUTMFkqrsATBvctdzhiL6Xy5aLNGv3cCibyNpyqq%252BOT%252FqPQc%252BIEMCtb5lb%252Bu%252FDsX9bMN9H0sVNr8BufCpRxTq%252FpU3UDFl%252BgggNo36OI7%252F4x8qOI0R3TLWxd9bVsLYG2k5RCC4iXV2tGreAwrBFQ8HD%252BQ9nz5dTF643j95ZZ%252FGyDmfA9wZZuZLK6MqQahvEAi%252FPbQ%252F6lYJsB9u5LH2k8pO00TprmaxfM8l8AZ%252FT6Tw1%252BSN9MhOrqZONDsjgOClOWGeuWRfz6pIYNFTYsMuCJdyL2rybbsuQlsV7%252BGtzn6i%252FNfBauvET90STfYzbJS71neRSMjoeePwVLgzbrE8MTsgZ%252FcgEWG5YN%252BXUsjPzmy%252BfKCX9rbOCJKPWh8pl%252Bjk64vRIDJMikQvNGmsx2vPGCsAKJX5ONv6zEfC%252F91yi4pjqv5wmwYyN%252BQN6FuQDNwiRZ4TZl%252Bq34WnBGKXRQHz3cMIs3c8LAHq8ZKopMmcxU%252FFHOq2VuYL%252BuYAe5x25Dk0feI%252FIPZx4NSVgqvHOnDB2GzpbcxlIMInIS6pb0XRIq%252B4tbfPfGnwJ7aO2x%252B9AKczrNtUQl00StGKIubdxdWqP%252FxuQqrDqPm9Zdq1BGBt3LVco4EErDbm%252BEr6UHtvORMIJkvAMF%252BeKkbyqfrzokSP5d6HXnzHJbiNRahP16f4oi5amKJKsWZQ8lGpQ0LXz%252BnBmJg224gGtFb2WPw%252B4uVLNyNHpILCOAvUzMUx0Ty1zVug1PGSHcZdMTFfNmCEqWumRS0Rx3aAKIzsuHcskyCg1qT7Y5WnX5IZsfTwzuI8IIaMBdh5tDew4UiVOz9JAxoQJP%252FmxMIkShCVGm60c2glLCjWM6NVVtR0dPLtMGRHGx5lYz3Xhdl28HNdoP68gPY%252BmnZ1%252BckcpnmoMRupyuzIBjj%252FCKmylImtcBMt6BgkAZyuP%252F8%252BCI71s%252Fmvt0Vf4kiGjEA3RvxsUTvrtBBjfPkXI8i7WKMnRlOHWUmKUJ%252BExdkDqTeND6cGKMZzgyfAHgwbWf57%252BNuIrgnn6HrY%252BCmygM4xbKeNdKEJ%252BI0gQ4hvyBWo0dhDyEJN28QGyh4JCC2FsZuFosBqRVchv14A91xtHeJYjsmvlvlrDR%252F2nnLJwRsfmmOz9m2VqIF%252FNRyrpusxq0wets10HAEt1Y%252BeoXETM6j1EFaXKe05qE6Scf6J7l82vh2HSvvZkBO2%252Bci%252FsTeDIN5vDhXAbNJ%252FSXnCXC7TeU7GT6ntmZcTfR9HzcvhcyBSSU7j7SfmrBvQKu3WdjuZEX85ikQXACydSnmAXFwN1mJzvBkbtpinu1Q6pVzTEmDjaOD67HbEuIzqPM0TVwUT2ihqd6JvFaHvasaoThIKeoQ%253D%253D","value":[{"id":"8ce1c3fd-972b-4821-a222
```

Error page returned:

```json
{
  "error": {
    "code": "UnknownError",
    "message": "<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd\">\r\n<html xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\">\r\n<head>\r\n<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\"/>\r\n<title>404 - File or directory not found.</title>\r\n<style type=\"text/css\">\r\n<!--\r\nbody{margin:0;font-size:.7em;font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;background:#EEEEEE;}\r\nfieldset{padding:0 15px 10px 15px;} \r\nh1{font-size:2.4em;margin:0;color:#FFF;}\r\nh2{font-size:1.7em;margin:0;color:#CC0000;} \r\nh3{font-size:1.2em;margin:10px 0 0 0;color:#000000;} \r\n#header{width:96%;margin:0 0 0 0;padding:6px 2% 6px 2%;font-family:\"trebuchet MS\", Verdana, sans-serif;color:#FFF;\r\nbackground-color:#555555;}\r\n#content{margin:0 0 0 2%;position:relative;}\r\n.content-container{background:#FFF;width:96%;margin-top:8px;padding:10px;position:relative;}\r\n-->\r\n</style>\r\n</head>\r\n<body>\r\n<div id=\"header\"><h1>Server Error</h1></div>\r\n<div id=\"content\">\r\n <div class=\"content-container\"><fieldset>\r\n  <h2>404 - File or directory not found.</h2>\r\n  <h3>The resource you are looking for might have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.</h3>\r\n </fieldset></div>\r\n</div>\r\n</body>\r\n</html>\r\n",
    "innerError": {
      "date": "2021-08-03T15:17:47",
      "request-id": "612e5911-2856-4fe1-a63b-ff0a11c6efaf",
      "client-request-id": "612e5911-2856-4fe1-a63b-ff0a11c6efaf"
    }
  }
}

{
  "ServerInfo": {
    "DataCenter": "South Central US",
    "Slice": "E",
    "Ring": "3",
    "ScaleUnit": "003",
    "RoleInstance": "SN1PEPF0000B6A3"
  }
}
Request ID '78f49331-e1f8-46d4-a586-9164e49deff8' at 2021-08-03T16: 09: 09 UTC
```

Comment: How persistent is this issue?

Comment: It seems to have fixed itself today.  The NextLink is returning correctly.  ~900 responses per call for a total of ~3K.

Comment: Okay, monitor and get back if the issue still existing.